# Race condition in a Java Servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, race-condition

I have this weird problem where two separate users upload a picture to my web service and user1 see's user2's error messages. Reviewing the code nothing sticks out to me, so I would like to ask what is wrong with this code and why was it creating this condition where errors for user2 would be visible to user1?

Here is some simplified code to try and demonstrate the situation.

```
public class SomeService {

    private static SomeService service;
    private SomeService() {
    }

    public static SomeService getInstance() {
        if(service == null) {
           service = new SomeService();
        }
    }

    public ErrorStatus doSomething(ErrorStatus es) {

        es = new ErrorStatus(es);
        // stuff happens that causes an error
        es.addMessage(new ErrorMessage("some error happened"));
        return es;
    }

    public ErrorStatus doSomethingElse(ErrorStatus es) {

        es = new ErrorStatus(es);
        // stuff happens that causes an error
        es.addMessage(new ErrorMessage("some different error happened"));
        return es;
    }
}

public class ErrorMessage {
    String message;

    //simple constructor, getters and setters, nothing interesting
}

public class ErrorStatus {
    int id;
    String status;
    List<ErrorMessage> messages;

    public ErrorStatus() {
         id = 0;
         status = "";
         messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ErrorStatus(ErrorStatus other) {
        id = other.getId();
        status = other.getStatus();
        messages = other.getMessages();
    }

    public void addMessage(ErrorMessage message) {

        //data checks
        messages.add(message);
    }

    //getters and setters
}   

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public doGet(request, response) {

        ErrorStatus es = new ErrorStatus();
        SomeService service = SomeService.getInstance();

        es = service.doSomething(es);

        es = service.doSomethingElse(es);

        printErrors(response.getWriter(), es);

    }

    public void printErrors(PrintWriter pw, ErrorStatus es) {

        for(int i = 0; i < es.getMessages().size(); i++) {

            pw.write(es.getMessages().get(i).getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The two places in the code I think something weird could be happening is the copy constructor or the fact that the service is a singleton. Maybe I'm not copying the list correctly, or maybe the service being a singleton changes how the stack and heap are used, I'm really not sure. From my understanding of how the stack, heap, singletons and servlets work one users data would never be affected by another users data.
Also they only part of this that ever had problems was the list, the primitive data was always correct, only the list of errors was ever showing up for the wrong user.

I should note, I have solved the problem I just don't understand why it was a problem. The solution was to stop using the copy constructor and to just let the ErrorStatus object get modified in the doSomething and doSomethingElse methods. So the revised code would have a void return type for doSomething and would just call es.addMessage, also the copy constructor was deleted from ErrorStatus.

Any help understanding why this caused a race condition would be appreciated.

Comment: The snippet you posted is absolutely correct. Are you sure that `SomeService` has not *any* instance variable? In that case the instance variable would be shared among all `SomeService` clients

Comment: Yes, I have been very careful to not have class level variables in the service, everything is scoped to the method it is used in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in this line:

`messages = other.getMessages();`

Basically this means that two different `ErrorStatus` objects are sharing the same `List` and modifications to one list would affect the other and vice versa. This line should look like

`messages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>(other.getMessages());`

This way, the list will (initially) contain the same elements but will be immune to modification side effects.

Comment: But how would that 'leak' data between two completely separate sessions from different users hitting the server from different machines? I understand how that could cause errors for one user, I'm just not understanding how my data is leaking between sessions and threads.

Comment: It could be that you are inadvertently sharing some objects across the sessions, e.g. through a servlet or some static attribute. The code you pasted looks all correct but I assume this was only a simplified version of what you have. Anyway, it would be interesting to know if my suggestion made any difference.

Comment: There are no static attributes, the example is only simplified in that only code that uses the ErrorStatus object was included. The ErrorStatus object is local to the servlet, it's instantiated in the doGet method and isn't used anywhere outside the scope of the doGet, in the example and the actual code. I agree I think what you suggested would probably fix the problem but my original question is 'why is it a problem', not 'how do I fix it'. Which is why I haven't accepted your answer, I'm hoping someone can explain why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with one of the responses in that, it's hard to figure out the problem from your simplified code. Some typos/errors I noticed:

```
public static SomeService getInstance() {
    if(service == null) {
       service = new SomeService();
    }
    **return service;**
}

public doGet(request, response) {

    ErrorStatus es = new ErrorStatus();
    SomeService service = SomeService.getInstance();

    es = service.doSomething(es); //<-- This first one never gets tracked; es is overwritten below.

    es = service.doSomethingElse(es); 

    printErrors(response.getWriter(), es);

}

public ErrorStatus() {
     id = 0; **<-- How exactly does id increase?**
     status = ""; 
     messages = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In any case, check if you have member variables in either SomeService or UploadServlet. I am learning about race conditions myself; I suspect you have a problem where two users are accessing a shared resource, and that the interleaving/timing of their access is the problem.

For a simple example, a user might:
get servlet instance (gsi) --> do actions (da) --> log errors (le) --> read errors (re).

Two users may interleave operations.

User1: gsi       -->      da      -->         le           -->     re

User2:   **__**  gsi     -->     da          -->         le       -->      re.

So when user1 reads errors, he's actually reading the errors by user2, who just completed logging the error. Your UploadServlet may have a member ErrorStatus object: that would create the problem.

Good luck!

here's a good tutorial: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23947

Comment: the doSomething and doSomethingElse methods create new ErrorStatus objects using the copy constructor so everything in es does move between the functions. I think the issue came down to how the copy constructor was working. Which I still don't understand, but for some reason using the assignment operator, see my example code, instead of creating new objects caused the problems.